# Using arcpy.GetParameterAsText() or arcpy.GetParameter() to pass datetime.timedelta to script?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, parameters

I have a function that takes a `datetime.timedelta` as an argument in a script that I want to use in ModelBuilder.  I don't see an option for that as a parameter type, so for now I have a solution that involves setting the parameter as a `String` in ModelBuilder and the following code:

```
...
startOffset = eval('datetime.timedelta(' + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + ')')
...
```

Which works, but relies on inputting a valid set of `timedelta` arguments for the parameter in ModelBuilder (e.g. `days=0,hours=3`) and just seems like a bad idea in general.

Is there a better way to get a `timedelta` into a script from a Model using only one parameter?

Comment: Why not try it as two `float` parameters, one for days and one for seconds and then do `datetime.timedelta(float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)), float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)))`

Comment: My main reservation with that is that I'd either need to insist that users convert to the appropriate units or require 7 parameters to actually specify any possible initialization for it (i.e. `timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])`.  As it is, there's 1 parameter to specify any combination of values.

Comment: What do your users actually need to be able to input? What does the value mean?

Comment: Making a tool to find flights in an area during a time period relative to another event.  So they'd put in a `timedelta` relative to the start of the event and another one relative to the end of the event to specify the time period that they want to see flights for.

Comment: Why not just use two dates as a range and use the subtraction operator to get the delta when you need it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'use two dates as a range and use the subtraction operator'.  It sounds like you're suggesting that I calculate a `timedelta` for the range, but that's not what I'm looking for.  The date range is already in the data that I'm using - it's the time during which something was occurring (as start + end times) and doesn't change.  I want to be able to modify that range based on provided `timedelta`s, not calculate what the `timedelta` is for the existing range.  Or am I misinterpreting your comment?

Comment: use timedelta.total_seconds() and pass as a long?

Answer (score 1):

This article discusses [parsing human-readable timedeltas in Python](http://blog.posativ.org/2011/parsing-human-readable-timedeltas-in-python/). It can be extended to include seconds, milliseconds, and microseconds, depending on your specifications (and knowledge of regexps), but primarily just allows the input to be specified in a more human-readable string format:

e.g.:

```
>>> tdelta("1m")
datetime.timedelta(0, 60)
>>> tdelta("1h")
datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
>>> tdelta("1d")
datetime.timedelta(1)
>>> tdelta("1w")
datetime.timedelta(7)
>>> tdelta("1w 1d 1h 1m")
datetime.timedelta(8, 3660)
```

As for whether this is actually any better than what you are doing now only you could answer.

Code for posterity:

```
import re
from datetime import timedelta

def tdelta(input):

    keys = ["weeks", "days", "hours", "minutes"]
    regex = "".join(["((?P<%s>\d+)%s ?)?" % (k, k[0]) for k in keys])
    kwargs = {}
    for k,v in re.match(regex, input).groupdict(default="0").items():
        kwargs[k] = int(v)
    return timedelta(**kwargs)
```

Comment: That's interesting, but my original issue isn't really with the number of characters necessary to input the parameter, but with the fact that the parameter is having to be parsed into a `timedelta` instead of finding a way to actually pass it in as one.  For my purposes I don't think the few characters saved in the input by doing this outweighs the fact that you're now relying on people knowing a non-standard set of arguments for the `timedelta` they're trying to create.